# passport.authenticate('local') doesn't redirect to some page

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I wanted to make a login system with Passport. Everything went well until I tried to login with an username and a password. On invalid/wrong credentials it warns me with a flash message but on valid credentials it justs spins there for an eternity and does literally nothing.

Here's the code

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");
const passport = require("passport");


router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("users/register");
});

router.post("/register", catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const {email, username, password} = req.body;
    const user = new User({email, username});
    await User.register(user, password);
    req.flash("success", "Welcome to Yelp Camp!");
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash("error", e.message);
        res.redirect("/register");
    }
}));

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("users/login");
});

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: "/login"}), (req, res) => {
    req.flash("success", "WELCOME BACK!");
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
})

module.exports = router;
```

Even tried with successRedirect from the docs but the results it's still the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should create a `get` route with this path, you didn't define this route in your project

```
res.redirect("/campgrounds")
```

put complate Url as argument to res.redicret

```
res.redirect("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/campgrounds")
```

Comment: Yes, I did but it's on other file. it should definetly work but I still don't see why

Comment: campgrounds is a static path? or is a route?

Comment: It's a route, (I suppose, I put the campground routes in a different file) if you look upper in my code,  you will see that ``` res. redirect("/campgrounds") ``` worked at register path.

Comment: I will try asap I reach the computer, thanks!

Comment: Still the same result, even with res.send() or console.log() but thanks for trying

Comment: Suppose you want to request `/campgrounds` by postman, put that url in res.redirect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227894/discussion-between-scythe-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).